# How do I get the name and URL alias of a vocabulary using only  the vid?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I need the URL alias of the vocabulary, not the term and not the machine name; I need the name that appears to the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [taxonomy_vocabulary_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_vocabulary_load/7) to obtain the machine name of a specific vid.

Example usage:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_load($vid);
$machine_name = $vocabulary->machine_name;
$name = $vocabulary->name;
```

Vocabularies aren't exposed to the user like terms are, so they don't really have an url-alias. The name which is presented in the vocabulary list is `$name` in the above code.

Comment: At least not something that is public. Vocabularies can only "viewed" in the administrative list of terms. The path to that is `admin/structure/taxonomy/ ' . $vocabulary->machine_name`.

Comment: I noticed the admin path, and then attempted to access `taxonomy/<machine_name>` only to see "page not found". I have wished for such functionality before.

Comment: Technically vocabularies CAN have a URL aliases if you set one just as I have. I'm creating a custom directory and I need to have links back to the upper category level and in some cases that upper category level is simply the vocabulary URL where it starts. Thanks anyway, I can just use either a vid list and return the URL or just access the database directly from code and get it that way, no biggie.

Comment: Yes, the URL is above in my comment, and if you pass that through url() or l(), it will automatically use the url alias if there is one. When developing, always work with internal system url's, url() and similar functions will take care of aliasing for you.